# Open javascript window after scrolling

Tags: javascript

I have searched and i didnt found nothing to help me... I created a javascript function to open a window when i click in a picture...But my screen has a lot of pictures , and when i scroll down and click in the picture, the window doesnt open where i am in the window, it opens in the beggining of the page..

```
    function CreateWindow()
    {       
    vWidth = '300';
    vHeight = '300';
    var Title = '';

    var div = document.body;
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<div id='telamodal' class='telamodal'></div>";

    var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    var vleft = ((screen.width * ratio)/2)-(vWidth/2);
    var vtop = ((screen.height * ratio)/2)-(vHeight/1.5);                   

    var divTelaConfirma = document.getElementById('telamodal'); 
    divTelaConfirma.innerHTML = divTelaConfirma.innerHTML + "<div id='telaetapa' class='telaetapa'></div>";

    document.getElementById("telaetapa").style.width=vWidth + 'px';
    document.getElementById("telaetapa").style.height=vHeight + 'px';               
    document.getElementById("telaetapa").style.top= vtop + 'px';
    document.getElementById("telaetapa").style.left= vleft + 'px';                          

    var divCaixaConfirma = document.getElementById('telaetapa');    
    divCaixaConfirma.innerHTML = divCaixaConfirma.innerHTML + "<div id='telaetapa_titulo' class='telaetapa_titulo'></div>";

    var divCaixaTitulo = document.getElementById('telaetapa_titulo');   
    divCaixaTitulo.innerHTML = divCaixaTitulo.innerHTML + "<h id='telaetapatitulo_texto'>" + Title + "</h><img src='imagens/fechartela.png' id='but_fechartela' class='but_fechartela'/>";

    var divCaixaConfirma1 = document.getElementById('telaetapa');   
    divCaixaConfirma1.innerHTML = divCaixaConfirma1.innerHTML + "<div id='telaetapa_corpo' class='telaetapa_corpo'></div>";

    OpenScreen('telamodal');    
}

function OpenScreen(elementname) 
   {
       el = document.getElementById(elementname);
       el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
   }
```

Someone could help me? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved very simply with some styling; a simple solution would be just to make the window you're create fixed instead of absolute (I'm guessing it's absolutely positioned based on its behavior you've described).

Consider the following update:

**In your CSS file where you style `.telamodal`**

```
.telamodal{
    position: fixed;
    ...
}
```

By giving this element a fixed position on the screen, it will stay in place (relative to its location on the screen) regardless of how you scroll.

If for some reason a `fixed` element is no good for your particular project, the other solution would be to add an offset (based on the distance the user is from the top of the element) to the `top` attribute of your element.